# (SQL) Is it possible to update a field value with the value of the field in the previous row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table from which I would like the update the value of a certain colum of fields.

Basicly moving one value down and those under it should inherit the previous value of the one about them.

I wonder if this action is possible using a single SQL query.

**My table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `menu` (
  `slot_index` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `language_ID` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `menuItem` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`slot_index`,`language_ID`),
  KEY `language_ID` (`language_ID`)
)
```

**The content in it:**

```
INSERT INTO `menu` (`slot_index`, `language_ID`, `menuItem`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Home'),
(2, 1, 'Wie zijn wij'),
(21, 1, 'Missie'),
(22, 1, 'Doelen'),
(23, 1, 'Visie'),
(24, 1, 'Test'),
(3, 1, 'Wat doen wij'),
(31, 1, 'Medische kaart voor op reis'),
(32, 1, 'Huisartsenkaart'),
(33, 1, 'Huisartsenkaart anderstaligen'),
(4, 1, 'Perskamer'),
(5, 1, 'Beheer'),
(6, 1, 'FAQ'),
(7, 1, 'Ervaringen'),
(8, 1, 'Contact'),
(81, 1, 'Disclaimer'),
(9, 1, 'Links'),
(91, 1, 'Adresgegevens')
```

I would like to move `slot_index` 5 to 9, and make the fields under it move up inheriting the value from the field above.

Is this possible with a single query at all, or should I just write a script for this?

Thanks in advance.

Wolfert

Comment: If you feel the need to change the value of the primary key then that field should probably not be part of the primary key.

Comment: Also, have you thought about how you will write an ORDER BY clause for that sorting order? You can't just use ORDER BY slot_id. How have you solved this? What will happen when there are more than 9 items in the menu?

Comment: I'd also recommend that you read this page on storing heirarchical data in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: These models and some other approaches are very good described in the Joe Celko`s book Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties -> http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/1558609202

Comment: Yeah that's the illogical part,

I thought this up for a menu which is only 9 slots wide at any given time, but every menu slot can have several subslots.

Every single digit is a main slot, every second digit indicates a subslot.
The menu is then rendered in a php script. 

I understand how silly this design is. I would have rewritten it if not for the customer who filled it up with 25 languages already.

But I'm afraid I don't have much alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using auto increment will help for future uses.

As for the current one I doubt that this can go with single query, because you cant query the table you are trying to update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but an autoincrement is no option as i need every single digit as main slot, while every second digit should indicates a subslot.